# How to redirect page with ajax?

Tags: ajax

Is it possible to redirect a page, not with window.location.href, ie reloading the page, but ajax, without reloading the page.

```
url = "google.com"; 

// Instead of reloading the page with that, there has t he writing ajax not reload the page? 

window.location.href = url;
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://google.com"></script> 
<script> 
    $('#theForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
    window.location.href = "I want the user to be redirected to this page";
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know there are two ways to do this.

1. You can send a request to the server and let the server redirect the request to the url you want.
2. You can also send the request to server via ajax and the server return the whole page as reponse. Then you can replace the current page with this response.

   $.post(url,function(response){ $('body').empty().append(response) });